# Selected option not working for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this select which works fine, but default the select is empty and doesn't show the selected value (which is filled correctly):

```
<%= f.select(:relationgroup, options_for_select(@relationgroups), { :selected => @relation.relationgroup, :include_blank => true}) %>
```

Any idea why? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it that way:

```
<%= f.select(
        :relationgroup, 
        options_for_select(@relationgroups, @relation.relationgroup), 
        :include_blank => true
) %>
```

Not sure, but maybe it'll work better.

Anyway, assuming `Relationgroup` is some model with `id` and `name` (or any other attribute that you want to be visible in select options) attributes, and you're using default `relationgroup_id` foreign key in your model you'd better construct your select like that:

```
<% f.select(
       :relationgroup_id,
       options_from_collection_for_select(@relationgroups, :id, :name),
       :include_blank => true
) %>
```

It'll choose selected value based on `object.relationgroup_id` where `object` is the model you're building form for. See [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select) for more information.

Comment: The first one, because it is a string field, no id's involved.